# error in getting userinfo from google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I am sending get request to foll. url: http://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/about?access_token=ya29.AHES6ZTVRK_UNXzjbUh7KAdh2eiU7-gOYnrMTAPH7dDvUjpY7OEZpQ&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive  but I do not get any reply for this request.I want to get name of user logged in and I am foll. this link to get required information https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get  I am using access token instead of api key and under my assumption it should not be a problem due to that since it is required for authorization only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try that URL I get {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"sslRequired","message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}],"code":403,"message":**"SSL is required to perform this operation**."}}

Assuming that you did in fact use https, and your access token is valid, you will get some response. You'll need to post the error status and response body (both available from Chrome devtools) in order to get any more assistance.

Comment: thanks got it solved ,was sending http instead of https request